# Subir imagen a mysql con php , no me admite el tamaño de la imagen

Tags: php, mysql

Al intentar subir una imagen de 4KB me lo permite pero cuando intento subir una imagen de 4 o 5 MB no me perite subirla , me dice que el formato esta incorrecto.

```
<?php
extract($_POST);    //extraer todos los valores del metodo post del formulario de actualizar
$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contraseña = "";
$bd = "bdpagina";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");

$nombre_img = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
$tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];
if (($nombre_img == !NULL) && ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= 100000000)) 
{
  //indicamos los formatos que permitimos subir a nuestro servidor
  if (($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
  || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  {
    // Ruta donde se guardarán las imágenes que subamos
    $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/modulo/images/';
    // Muevo la imagen desde el directorio temporal a nuestra ruta indicada anteriormente
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$nombre_img);
  } 
  else 
  {
    //si no cumple con el formato
    echo "No se puede subir una imagen con ese formato ";
  }
} 
else 
{
  //si existe la variable pero se pasa del tamaño permitido
  if($nombre_img == !NULL) echo "La imagen es demasiado grande "; 
}


$sentencia = "UPDATE contribuyente SET estado = '$estado', comentario = '$comentario', servicio = '$servicio' , fecha_rec ='$fecharec' , imagen='$nombre_img' WHERE contribuyente. id = '$id'";
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
$resent=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
if ($resent==null) {
  echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
  echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';
  echo "<script>location.href='usuario.php'</script>";
}else {


  echo "<script>location.href='usuario.php'</script>";  

}
?>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, has probado en mirar el archivo php.ini para comprobar si tiene algún tipo de limitación? o te genera un error SQL? Si lo compruebas edita esta linea -> upload_max_filesize = 2M

Comment: modifique esa fila y aun asi no me deja insertar imágenes de 4mb

Answer (score 1):

tienes que configurar el php.ini 
pero si lo quieres hacer solo en ese php intenta

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1536M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un archivo .htaccess y colocar lo siguiente

```
php_value memory_limit 30M 
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

la segunda linea `php_value post_max_size 100M` debe ser mayor que las dos restantes.

O si tienes acceso a `php.ini` busca las siguientes lineas y modifica los valores que tiene por los que sean más convenientes según el peso de los archivos que realizaran el upload.

```
post_max_size=100M
upload_max_filesize=30M
```

Nota: Si modificas el archivo `php.ini` tendrás que reiniciar tu servidor apache

Answer (score 0):

Así como deben revisar el php.ini, también debe verificar el tipo de valor en la base de datos, tal vez este utilizando TINYBLOG y por esa razón no le admite imágenes más grandes.